# Is it possible to parallelize or unroll this loop?

Tags: multithreading, performance, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am trying to see if I can improve the performance of the following loop in C++,  which uses two dimensional vectors (_external and _Table) and has a carried loop dependency on the previous iteration. Additionally, it has a calculated index accessor in the innermost loop that will make the access of _Table non sequential on the right hand side.

```
int N = 8000;
int M = 400
int P = 100;
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
        for(int k =0; k < P; k++){
            int index = _external.at(j).at(k);
            _Table.at(j).at(i) += _Table.at(index).at(i-1);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to improve the performance of a loop like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks to me like the order in which these statements:

```
    int index = _external.at(j).at(k);
    _Table.at(j).at(i) += _Table.at(index).at(i-1);
```

are executed is critical to correctness.  (That is, if the iteration order for i, j, k changes, then the results will be different ... and incorrect.)

So I think you are only left with micro-optimizations, like hoisting the expressions `_Table.at(j).at(i)` and `_external.at(j)` out of the innermost loop.

Consider this:

```
    for(int k =0; k < P; k++){
        int index = _external.at(j).at(k);
        _Table.at(j).at(i) += _Table.at(index).at(i-1);
    }
```

This loop is repeatedly adding numbers to `_Table.at(j).at(i)`.  Since (by inspection) `_Table.at(index).at(i-1)` must be reading from a different cell of the table (because of `i-1` versus `i`), you could do this:

```
    int temp = 0;
    for(int k =0; k < P; k++){
        int index = _external.at(j).at(k);
        temp += _Table.at(index).at(i-1);
    }
    _Table.at(j).at(i) += temp;
```

This will reduce the number of calls to `at`, and may also improve cache performance a bit.

Comment: Thank you - yes I had already experimented with hoisting that temp variable. It did not make that much of a difference in execution time. I had just posted the "original" version of the code to make sure that I wasn't missing something. I suspect I will have to go back to the drawing board and see if I can figure out a different way to get to a correct result for my algorithm without using this type of loop. Thanks